# Represent a file with 0x00 as a string

Tags: c++, file

I want to represent my file as a string but I have a problem the file contains a 0x00 and my string gets terminated right there.How to solve this?

Comment: The best way to help you is for you to show us your failed attempt.

Comment: What is a "string" here? We need to see the relevant code.

Comment: I have a txt file like this in binary 0x61 0x61 0x61 0x00 0x62 0x62 0x62. When I read the file binary and save it in a string I get only this 0x61 0x61 0x61.

Comment: Chris means, "show us your code".

Comment: @user2357536 - Here's the problem. Your file, is not a string. It may be a series of strings or just general binary data.  I don't know because you didn't speak as to what you are really trying to do.  Do you just want to get the human readable portions of the file into a single string so you can print the content?  Or do you need to parse away the null chars that signal end of string?  I suspect the real problem is that you are in fact saving a series of strings to file - but aren't stripping off the null char of each record (and replacing it with a more reasonable delimiter such as \n)

Comment: I know it is not a string but I need to represent it as a string.But the problem is that the file have many null chars.How to deal with them?

Comment: It's impossible for us to tell you "how to deal with them" with no more information. Please [edit] your question to make it more specific (adding anything in comments isn't useful). If you want help here, you need to be specific and provide details **in your question**.

Comment: The standard library `std::string` can contain 0x00 bytes (it doesn't use null termination). Alternately you can use `std::vector<char>` to hold your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use the null as the termination character you have very few options:

a) write the string size prior to the string:
     005Hello
     011Hello\0World

b) use fixed length strings

c) prepend non-terminating nulls with a special char like '\'.  If '\' appears in your string, write it twice "\".  Reverse the logic when reading them back.

Comment: Since the question is tagged C++ I think this answer is misleading. There are more (and better) options for representing strings in C++ than those listed here.

Answer (score 1):

*I have a txt file like this in binary 0x61 0x61 0x61 0x00 0x62 0x62 0x62*

"txt file" in binary ? - I don't know what does it mean .

But if you have values separated by spaces you can try using `std::vector` of `std::string`
(which doesn't use null termination)

```
std::ifstream fin("input.txt");

 std::vector<std::string> v;
 std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string> (fin),
           std::istream_iterator<std::string> (), 
           std::back_inserter(v) );

std::vector<std::string>::iterator it =v.begin();

for(;it!=v.end();++it)                       
  std::cout<< *it<<" ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read your file in binary mode:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string read_file_as_string(const char* filename) {
  std::ifstream input(filename, std::ios::binary);
  if (!input) {
    std::perror("Great failure");
    std::exit(1);
  }

  std::stringstream contents;
  contents << input.rdbuf();
  return contents.str();
}

int main() {
  std::string s = read_file_as_string("Derp.exe");
  std::cout << "s.size() = " << s.size() << '\n';
  for(unsigned char c : s) {
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(c) << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```